# why do I get 2 ports when I portforward using ngrok

Tags: python, port, portforwarding, ngrok

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxN73.jpg)

As you can see from the image above I'm given 2 ports what's the use of them? As I understood you only need 1 why am I given 2?

Comment: Please don't put stuff vital to the question in a picture. It makes it harder for us to diagnose your problems, and also your question will become invalidated when the host of the picture inevitably goes down. In your output it seems as though you've tried to create a TCP-tunnel via ngrok. What we cannot know is what commands you've executed to get the output. Please update the question to include 1. Your output in text-form 2. The commands you've thrown to replicate the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out ngrok only opens a port while the application is open on a PC thus making it unusable I used portmap.io which gave me a free lifetime open port I recommend using that.